# WAP application Example

Tags: android

maybe this is a stupid question.. but, is Google Maps app on Android an example of WAP application? and can anybody provide me example of WAP Application?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Do you need further explanations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [WAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol) is a standard protocol for mobile phones and mobile telecomunications.

An android application is not tied to a specific standard or protocole. It just uses the connection provided by the android phone. This connection could either be a [3G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G) connection or a Wifi connection. (Or a WAP connection, but this standard is getting old)

To summarise Google Maps uses a connection to get localisation data etc. But the Google Maps application is not "aware" of the caracteristics of that connection. It is just using whatever available connection through a sort of wrapper.

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask if you need more explanations. :)

Comment: You can pick an answer as "The answer of your question" to make it easier for futur readers to understand if the questions has been answered or not.